# How can I grab the content of a DOM element only once if selecting an entire tree which also contains those same nested elements?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, microsoft-translator

For example: Targeting the container element (div#container) by id (getElementById) returns an HTML Collection containing each element and all of it's properties including the children nodes repeated within each nested item. Then I iterate each item into an array but I'm left with the same data repeated in each level of the DOM tree.

```
    0: <div class="container"><div><div><main><footer><div class="container-fluid"><p> © 2018-2020 Copyright:  </p></div></footer></main></div></div></div>
    1: <div><div><main><footer><div class="container-fluid"><p> © 2018-2020 Copyright: </p></div></footer></main></div></div>
    2: <div><main><footer><div class="container-fluid"><p> © 2018-2020 Copyright: </p></div></footer></main></div>
    3: <main><footer><div class="container-fluid"><p> © 2018-2020 Copyright: </p></div></footer></main>
    4: <footer><div class="container-fluid"><p> © 2018-2020 Copyright: </p></div></footer>
    5: <div class="container-fluid"><p> © 2018-2020 Copyright: </p></div>
    6: <p> © 2018-2020 Copyright: </p>
```

What I'd like to do is grab the actual content only once (e.g. `<p> © 2018-2020 Copyright: </p>`) -- and associate it with the correlating XPath location -- in order to re-assemble the HTML document later with just the containing structures above holding the element tags and attributes; only inserting the content into the last child of the node as illustrated below:

```
/DIV/DIV/DIV/MAIN/FOOTER/ --> `<div class="container-fluid"><p></p></div>`

/DIV/DIV/DIV/MAIN/FOOTER/DIV --> `<p></p>`

/DIV/DIV/DIV/MAIN/FOOTER/DIV/P --> © 2018-2020 Copyright:
```

**Background/Context:**
The goal of this is reduce redundancies in my array object in order to construct an efficient payload (eventually stringified to JSON) to send off to the Microsoft Translator API so that I'm not translating the same content nodes unnecessarily in order to reconstruct the translated page by injecting the translation text response back into their original DOM locations using XPath and jQuery.

So far I've used jQuery and the TreeWalker Web API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to accomplish what I have so far...

**JavaScript:**

```
       // Get all element nodes of page
        var content = document.getElementById('container');


        //array for DOM elements
        var b = [];

        function elementNodesUnder(el) {

          var n;

          nodeFilter = function(node) {

            if (node.innerHTML && node.tagName !== 'SCRIPT' && node.tagName !==
            'STYLE' && node.tagName !== 'svg' && node.tagName !== 'I' &&
            node.tagName !== 'VIDEO') {   return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;

            } else {

              return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
            }

          };

          walk = document.createTreeWalker(

            el,
            NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
            nodeFilter,
            false

          );

          while ((n = walk.nextNode())) b.push(n);
          return b;
        }


        elementNodesUnder(content);
        console.log(b);

    //array variables for xpath + innerHTML collections
    var xPathArray = [];
    var innerHTMLdinner = [];


    //loop through text nodes & assign xPath
    $.each(b, function(i, c) {

        if (c.innerHTML) {

          //console.log(i+" "+getElementXPath(c)+" = "+c.innerHTML);

          //push each corresponding item to an array for xpath + innerHTML
          xPathArray.push(getElementXPath(c));
          innerHTMLdinner.push(c.innerHTML);

        }

      });

      //map the xPath and innerHTML arrays together and then stringify
    var xpathNodeMap = xPathArray.map((xPathers, index) => ({xPathArray: xPathers, innerHTML: innerHTMLdinner[index]}));
    var xpathNodeMapJSON = JSON.stringify(xpathNodeMap);
    console.log(xpathNodeMapJSON);


      // given a document element returns the xpath string expression of that element.

      function getElementXPath(elt) {

        var path = '';

        for (; elt && elt.nodeType == 1; elt = elt.parentNode) {

          idx = getElementIdx(elt);
          xname = elt.tagName;
          if (idx > 1) xname += '[' + idx + ']';
          path = '/' + xname + path;

        }

        return path;

      }



      function getElementIdx(elt) {

        var count = 1;

        for (var sib = elt.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling) {

          if (sib.nodeType == 1 && sib.tagName == elt.tagName) count++;

        }


        return count;

      }
```

**HTML Example**:

```
<html>

<body>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<div id="container">

    <div class="layout">

        <div class="bodyContainer">

            <main class="wrapper">

                <footer class="full-standard">

                    <div class="container no-print">

                        <div class="row">

                            <img alt="" src="" />

                        </div> <!-- footer > div.row -->

                    </div> <!-- /div.container.no-print -->

                    <div class="footer-copyright>

                        <div class="container-fluid">

                            <p>&copy; 2020 Copyright</p>

                        </div> <!-- /div.container-fluid -->

                    </div> <!-- /div.footer-copyright -->

                </footer> <!-- /footer.full-standard -->

            </main> <!-- /main.wrapper -->

        </div> <!-- /div.bodyContainer-->

    </div> <!--/div.layout -->


</div> <!-- / div#container -->

</body>

</html>
```

**XPath Results Example**:

```
{
    "xPathArray": "/HTML/BODY/DIV[6]/DIV/DIV/MAIN/FOOTER/DIV[2]",

    "innerHTML": "<div class=\"container-fluid\"><p> © 2018-2020 Copyright: </p></div>"
}, 

{
    "xPathArray": "/HTML/BODY/DIV[6]/DIV/DIV/MAIN/FOOTER/DIV[2]/DIV",

    "innerHTML": "<p> © 2018-2020 Copyright: </p>"
}, 

{
    "xPathArray": "/HTML/BODY/DIV[6]/DIV/DIV/MAIN/FOOTER/DIV[2]/DIV/P",

    "innerHTML": " © 2018-2020 Copyright: "
}
```

Surprisingly I couldn't find anything too close to this question yet so I apologize if I missed it but any help to point me in the right direction would be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the element you want a unique id - then grabbing that element by the id and passing the innerText of that element to your handler?

```
   <p id='unique_id'> Some Text </p>

    document.getElementbById('unique_id')[0].innerHTML
```

you might need to fiddle with this a touch, but the general idea should work

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I thought about trying to tag all of my page regions with a unique ID (or even a sequence of IDs such as transateID1, translateID2, translateID3, etc.) however I would like to be able to translate an entire page's content from one language to another so unfortunately it is not just a single element that I am targeting and why my DOM collection includes the entire content container

Comment: you probably will need a recursive solution then ```recursiveSolution(htmlElement) { if(htmlElement.innerText !== '') { return htmlElement.innerText = translateFunction(htmlElement.innerText)} else if (htmlElement.innerHTML) { recursiveSoltuion(htmlElement.innerHTML)}}``` something like that - good luck